# Storing game preferences and saved games in a secure format

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, sprite-kit, persistence

This is from Apple docs:

> When you design a game that reports scores to Game Center, you should
>   also consider the security needs of your game. You want scores
>   reported to Game Center to be an accurate accounting of how players
>   are doing. Here are two suggestions:
>
> Store your game’s preferences and saved games in a secure format,
>   rather than in clear text. If your game’s data is stored in clear
>   text, a player can download the saved game data using iTunes, modify
>   it, and resync it back to the device. This may allow the player to
>   achieve a higher score than you intended. Always set reasonable
>   minimum and maximum values for a leaderboard.

I know that data can be stored into [.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5) file or .xml or  .json, even in a database. But all of that is non-encrypted plain text. What is considered as a secure format ? And what else methods/classes/techniques  can be used to store sensitive data ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a hacker is determined enough and has the proper skill set, your stored data can be usually compromised regardless of storage method. It boils down to what your app's real-world applications are and the time and effort you are willing to put into keeping the data safe. Below are some options for you to consider:

**NSUserDefaults**

One of the most common and simplest ways to store data. Data is not encrypted.

[Save string to the NSUserDefaults?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074483/save-string-to-the-nsuserdefaults)

**Plist Files**

Also a common way to store data. Data is not encrypted.

[Storing and Retrieving from a Plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373297/storing-and-retrieving-from-a-plist)

**CoreData**

Creates a model, manage relationship between different types of objects. By default, data is not encrypted.

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/85578/first-core-data-app-using-swift

**Keychain**

Arguably the most secure way to store data on a non-jailbroken device. Data is encrypted.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16459879/how-to-store-a-string-in-keychain-ios

**NSCoding**

As Whirlwind pointed out, this is yet another storage method.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

http://nshipster.com/nscoding/

**CommonCrypto Apple Framework**

Low-level C coding. Data is encrypted.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

**Custom approaches**

Store the data in the cloud thereby eliminate having it on the device altogether. Use the touch ID feature to authenticate the user and download the cloud data.

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-8-integrating-touch-id--cms-21949

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/KeychainTouchID/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: You can add a comment, if you like, for this method too (NSCoding) to improve answer quality more http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

Comment: @Whirlwind - Excellent addition. I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The safest place to store your data is in the [keychain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/02concepts/concepts.html), however it's still not 100% secure if users are on jailbroken devices. Follow Apple's guidelines on setting minimum and maximum values for a leaderboard.

[Here's another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544133/saving-game-score-locally-on-ios-device-is-security-needed) describing how you can store the information in an `NSDictionary` as `NSData` which is then encrypted and decrypted by your app.

Comment: Hi huhitschris, thanks for the quick reply. It's not about just highscore and leaderboard. It's about many values i.e. virtual money, players upgrades etc. So defining min/max values is not suitable. I will read about NSData method with encryption and try it to see the results. Can you post some code for keychain implementation if that's not a problem?

Comment: Keychain is as secure as your passcode, jailbreak or not. Using a longer passphrase is the way to gain more security.